# Clickatell - API access to billing log?

Tags: clickatell

I need to be able to access a log of all SMS that were sent. Is there a way to do this via their HTTP API? I haven't had much luck finding anything that reference this in their docs.

Comment: This isn't about programming. We're not cliatell support [Even if they think we are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342143/reach-out-to-clickatell)

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called 'callbacks' that can send an HTTP request to your server for every message you send. It will give you status updates about the message and the message charge. This allows you to build up whatever form of custom reporting that you may want.

https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/callback-(push-status-and-cost-notification)-advanced-message-send/

You send your message with the callback parameter... And you specify your URL to receive callbacks on your API connection on the website.

Comment: As I am wanting to send SMS to customers who have specifically requested for them -- and I need to charge them for the service -- I guess I should use callback value = 2? That'll let me know the final status of the SMS sending and can use it to determine if I should charge them or not?

Comment: I would set callback 3 so you can bill as soon as you are billed. If someone's handset is turned off, you don't want to wait a day for him to turn it on (then get final status) - and only then bill. Note that you will get more than one callback per message with callback 3, so dont bill twice.... This also allows you to build your own reporting system if you ever wanted to in future.

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain why `callback=3` instead of `callback=2`? Don't I want to know if the message ever makes it to the user (`004`) and bill for those? What's the point of all the other interim statuses?

Comment: Callback 3 gives you status 3 and 4 callbacks. Clickatell charges you on status 3 - thats the main reason... The network operators charge even if you send to numbers that are no longer valid, or if the phone is off for the duration of their retry period.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't access reporting features like that via API. You need to log in to your central dashboard to get that information.

You can, however, query the message status if you have the message ID, but I don't think that's quite what you're looking for.

(Disclosure: I work for Clickatell)

Comment: Can I get some sort of response I can get back whenever I send an SMS? Perhaps I can log that to a database and use it for my own "billing log?" The idea is that I will be sending SMS to certain customers who have signed up for my service -- then I need to bill them for each SMS sent.

Comment: https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/callback-(push-status-and-cost-notification)-advanced-message-send/ - callback value = 2?

Comment: When you send an SMS, you get a tracking code back for that message. If you use the callback system (i suggest using callback 3 further on up on this page), it passes that message id (apimsgid) for each callback so you know what message it is for.